# How do I delimit 2 words with "@" symbol?

Tags: java

I have a task from my university where I should prompt the user for 2 numbers one integer the other decimal and print their product in money format. The program should also take in two words delimited by @ symbol. I'm struggling to figure out the last portion of the task (two words delimited by @ symbol).

Everything else I understand fine.

This is the exercise

```
Sample run 1:
Enter a whole number: 4
Enter a decimal number: 6.854
Enter two words delimitated by @ symbol: Mango@15
```

Output:

```
The product of the 2 numbers: 27.416
The product in money format is: N$ 27.42
Assuming the user bought 4 Mango(s) costing N$ 6.85
The VAT to be charged is 15%, hence total due to be paid is N$ 31.53
```

This is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab02_Task4 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner info = new Scanner(System.in);
        int whole;
        System.out.println("Enter a whole number: ");
        whole = info.nextInt();
        double decimal;
        System.out.println("Enter a decimal number: ");
        decimal = info.nextDouble();
        String item;
        System.out.println("Enter two words delimitated by @ symbol: ");
        item = info.nextLine();
        
        String item2 = "Mango";
        double total = whole * decimal;
        double vatIncluded = (total * 0.15) + total;
        String s=String.valueOf(total);
        System.out.println("The product of the 2 numbers: " + total);
        String total2 = String.format("%.2f", total);
        System.out.println("The product in money format is: N$ " + (total2));
        String vatIncluded2 = String.format("%.2f", vatIncluded);
        System.out.println("Assuming the user bought " + whole + " " +  item2 + "(s) " + "costing N$ " + total2 + 
" The VAT to be charged is 15%, hence total due to be paid is N$ " + vatIncluded2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with that @item ?

Comment: I got it. The word before the `@` is the item, and the number after the `@` is that "tax" or in this case, the VAT. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: **Delimitated** might be a proper form of **delimit** but the form I've seen most often, with regard to computer science, is **delimited**.

Comment: use `split()`, or regex if you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use split to separate the two values like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String string = "value@anothervalue";
  String[] arr = string.split("@");
  System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr)); //[value, anothervalue]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int wholenumber = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    double decimal = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());
    String[] deli = input.nextLine().split("@");
    String item = deli[0];
    int tax = Integer.parseInt(deli[1]);
    double product = decimal*wholenumber;
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String rounded = formatter.format(product).substring(1);
    double finalprice = product*tax/100+product;
    System.out.println("The product of the 2 numbers: "+product);
    System.out.println("The product in money format is: N$"+rounded);
    System.out.println("Assuming the user bought "+wholenumber+" "+item+"s costing N$"+formatter.format(decimal).substring(1));
    System.out.println("The VAT to4 be charged is "+tax+"%, hence the total due to the paid is N$"+finalprice);
    //The VAT to be charged is 15%, hence total due to be paid is N$ 31.53
}
```

**Sample Run**

```
4
6.854
Mango@15
The product of the 2 numbers: 27.416
The product in money format is: N$27.42
Assuming the user bought 4 Mangos costing N$6.85
The VAT to4 be charged is 15%, hence the total due to the paid is N$31.5284
```

*With user prompts*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int wholenumber = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Enter a decimal number: ");
    double decimal = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Enter two words seperated by @ symbol: ");
    String[] deli = input.nextLine().split("@");
    String item = deli[0];
    int tax = Integer.parseInt(deli[1]);
    double product = decimal*wholenumber;
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String rounded = formatter.format(product).substring(1);
    double finalprice = product*tax/100+product;
    System.out.println("The product of the 2 numbers: "+product);
    System.out.println("The product in money format is: N$"+rounded);
    System.out.println("Assuming the user bought "+wholenumber+" "+item+"s costing N$"+formatter.format(decimal).substring(1));
    System.out.println("The VAT to4 be charged is "+tax+"%, hence the total due to the paid is N$"+finalprice);
    //The VAT to be charged is 15%, hence total due to be paid is N$ 31.53
}
```

**Sample Run**

```
Enter a number: 4
Enter a decimal number: 6.854
Enter two words seperated by @ symbol: Mango@15
The product of the 2 numbers: 27.416
The product in money format is: N$27.42
Assuming the user bought 4 Mangos costing N$6.85
The VAT to4 be charged is 15%, hence the total due to the paid is N$31.5284
```